# Error in Google Chrome Lighthouse's Best Practice audit regarding manifest 'short_name'?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools, manifest.json, lighthouse

I'm getting an error when using Google Chrome's new auditing features (Lighthouse). I get the following message as a failed audit:

> Manfiest's `short_name` will be truncated when displayed on homescreen

They suggest I make `short_name` less than 12 characters, which it already is.

### manifest.json

```
{
  "description": "This is a description of my site",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "name": "The Very Long Title of My Site",
  "short_name": "MySite",
  "start_url": ".",
  "theme_color": "#171c28",
  "main.css": "wp-content/themes/mikedpad/style.css",
  "main.js": "wp-content/themes/mikedpad/js/main.js",
  "manifest.js": "wp-content/themes/mikedpad/js/manifest.js",
  "vendor.js": "wp-content/themes/mikedpad/js/vendor.js"
}
```

I'm just trying to figure out if it's something wrong on Lighthouse's end, or is there something incorrect / invalid from the manifest that's failing this audit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem a few hours after posting this. Chrome tools are working as expected and the problem was in my PHP. Once my document was printing the correct tag into the `<head>` tag, the audit passed as it should.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```